# problem with ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I make a program using vb.net and the report I am using ReportViewer. but when i install the client computer that uses XP, the reports can not be accessed and the error message appears. please help

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to install the [Report Viewer Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6442) on the client's computer.